# Unable to use web-manager.chrome to automatically update the chrome driver (python/selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver-manager

this is my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

pip list :
[pip list : screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBXtd.png)

using python 3.10 / selenium : 3

the error message i got :
[error msg :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahE8c.png)

Any help would be appreciated thanks a lot in advance.
Regards,

Comment: I would be better if you place your error message as text in this post. Your image with error is cropped

Comment: i couldn't place the text since it's too long , i changed the screen shot , i added the full 
error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
opc = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),chrome_options=opc)
```

Comment: i still get the same error :

 File "C:\Users\wmahmoudi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\drivers\chrome.py", line 37, in get_latest_release_version
    self.browser_version = get_browser_version_from_os(self.chrome_type)
  File "C:\Users\wmahmoudi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\utils.py", line 152, in get_browser_version_from_os
    cmd_mapping = {
KeyError: 'google-chrome'